# Couch DB filter by key and sort by another field

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchrest

In couchdb I need to filter by key and which is done like this.

```
{
   "_id": "_design/test",
   "_rev": "6-cef7048c4fadf0daa67005fefe",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "all": {
           "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.blogId) {emit(doc.key, doc);} }"
       }
   }
}
```

However the results should be ordered by another key (doc.anotherkey). So using the same function how do I achieve both filtering and ordering by another key.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to query by single `key`, you can use the following map:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.blogId) {
    emit([doc.key, doc.anotherkey], 1);
  }
}
```

and query for `"KEY"` with `?startkey=["KEY"]&endkey=["KEY",{}]&include_docs=true`.

Here, according to the [collation specification of CouchDB](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/views/collation.html#collation-specification):

- `["KEY"]` is a value lesser than any `["KEY","OTHER"]` value (because longer arrays sort after their prefixes), but greater than any `["KEY2","OTHER"]` with `"KEY2" < "KEY"`;
- and `["KEY",{}]` is a value greater than any `["KEY","OTHER"]` value, **if `doc.otherkey` is never a JSON object** (because JSON objects comes after any other JSON value), but lesser than any `["KEY2","OTHER"]` with `"KEY2" > "KEY"`.

Of course this is not limited to strings. Any type of value will work, as long as the collation is right.

Remember to URL encode the values in `startkey` and `endkey`. For example, using `curl` and assuming your database is "DB":

```
curl 'http://localhost:5984/DB/_design/test/_view/all?startkey=%5B%22KEY%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22KEY%22,%7B%7D%5D&include_docs=true'
```

Note that I've used the `include_docs` query parameter, instead of emitting the entire document with `emit(..., doc)`, to save disk space. Query parameters are documented on [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html).

To sort results in descending order, use the `descending=true` query parameter and swap the values of `startkey` and `endkey` as [documented in the definitive guide book](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#reversed).

```
curl 'http://localhost:5984/DB/_design/test/_view/all?endkey=%5B%22KEY%22%5D&startkey=%5B%22KEY%22,%7B%7D%5D&include_docs=true&descending=true'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please let me know where to include include_docs=true in the above code chunk.

Comment: Also If I need to sort descending how do I do that?

Comment: @Dilshan, `include_docs=true` is a query option. I've added a sample command using `curl`, and a link to the documentation.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the replies and links Marcello.

Comment: This is very helpful! Any insight on to what is happening when setting endkey=["KEY",{}]? What exactly does the empty object {} tell CouchDB?

Comment: @FoxMulder900, fair question... I have edited the answer, hope it is clearer now...