# PouchDB: filtering, ordering and paging

Tags: sorting, couchdb, pouchdb

Very similar to these two CouchDB questions: [3311225](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311225/couchdb-sorting-and-filtering-in-the-same-view) and [8924793](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924793/couch-db-filter-by-key-and-sort-by-another-field), except that these approaches don't allow **partial matching**. Having e.g. these entries:

```
[{_id: 1, status: 'NEW', name: 'a'},
{_id: 2, status: 'NEW', name: 'aab'},
{_id: 3, status: 'NEW', name: 'ab'},
{_id: 4, status: 'NEW', name: 'aaa'},
{_id: 5, status: 'NEW', name: 'aa'}]
```

and key

```
[status, name, _id]
```

There seems to be no way to

1. filter these entries by *status* (full string match) and *name* (partial string match ~ `startsWith`)
2. order them by *id*
3. paginate them

because of the partial string match on *name*. The [high value unicode character \uffff](http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchapp/views/collation.html#string-ranges) that allows this partial match also causes to ignore the `_id` part of the key, meaning the resulting entries are not sorted by `_id`, but rather by status and name.

```
var status = 'NEW';
var name = 'aa'
var query = {
    startkey: [status, name],
    endkey: [status, name + '\uffff', {}],
    skip: 0,
    limit: 10
};
```

results in

```
[{_id: 5, status: 'NEW', name: 'aa'},
{_id: 4, status: 'NEW', name: 'aaa'},
{_id: 2, status: 'NEW', name: 'aab'}]
```

There is no option to sort in memory, as this would only sort the individual pages, and not the entire data set. Any ideas about this?